# Как сделать нижнюю часть рамки более толстой

Tags: delphi, delphi-7, vcl

У меня панель в панели `TPanel`. Внутренняя панель может выравниваться на всю клиентскую обл. внешней или нет. Как сделать так, чтобы нижняя часть внешней рамки была более толстой, а левая, правая и верхняя стандартного? Я пишу компонент который содержит в себе несколько панелей. И мне нужно чтобы между этими панелями оставался зазор, но только между верхней частью и нижней. Т.к я не использую сплиттеры между панелями а использую сообщение `WM_NCHITTEST`. хотелось бы чтоб рамка была потолще аля со сплиттером.

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: Как вариант - добавляйте еще по панели нужной ширины между рабочими панелями.

Comment: А нельзя ли ка кто изменить клиентскую часть  панели?

Comment: Moжно. Просто измените Padding

Comment: Не приведете кусок кода?

Comment: Уточните используемое выравнивание во вложенных панелях (надеюсь, хоть Align в D7 есть?)

Comment: Хотелось бы сделать выравнивание alClient.  т.е если пользователь выравнивает по всей клиентской части то внизу оставался padding . например 5 или больше pix . [вот так] ( https://yadi.sk/i/jdQj3DxtqHvrA).

Answer (score 4):

Вы можете воспользоваться "выравнивающими" свойствами `Margins` (необходимо выставить `AlignWithMargins` в `True`) и `Padding`.

Они задают границы выравнивания для вложенных(`Padding`) и внешних(`Margins`) контролов.

Эти свойства нагляднее задавать в инспекторе объектов (на "тестовых" контролах), и потом переносить в свой код:

```pascal
// задаем границу, которую наша панель будет держать до контрола, лежащего на форме выше нее:
myPanel.AlignWithMargins:=True;
myPanel.Margins.Top:=10; // расстояние между контролом выше и нашим = 10 пикселей.

// задаем границу, которую будут держать внутренние панели по отношению к нашей
// (отступ от границы нашей панели до вложенной - 3 пикселя)
myPanel.Padding.Bottom:=3;
```

Обратите внимание, что `Margins` действует тогда, когда для вашей панели (`Padding` - когда у внутренних контролов) свойство `Algin` <> `alNone`

---

Еще один способ - воспользоваться protected-методом AdjustClientRect:

```pascal
type
  TmyPanel = class(TPanel)
  protected
    procedure AdjustClientRect(var Rect: TRect); override;
  end;

procedure TmyPanel.AdjustClientRect(var Rect: TRect);
begin
  inherited AdjustClientRect(Rect);
  // уменьшаем границы клиентской области на нужные значения:
  Rect.Bottom:=Rect.Bottom - 10;
end;
```

Comment: Забыл сказать что у меня Delphi 7 и у  стандартной панели таких свойств нет.

Comment: @gregor с этого надо было начинать.

Comment: @gregor , добавил вариант выравнивания без наличия Margins и Padding.

Comment: @gregor, в способе 2 у нижней панели должен быть Align = alNone, т.к. выравнивание делается "вручную".

Comment: Метода AdjustClientRect нет в D7

Comment: Я бы разнес эти разные ответы в разные ответы.

Comment: @KromStern , AdjustClientRect тоже выносить в отдельный?

Answer (score 3):

Для Delphi 7, с учетом отсутствия таких свойств, можно воспользоваться protected-методом Resize и самому выставлять границы вложенных контролов (привожу только код, относящийся к изменению размеров):

```pascal
type
  TmyPanel = class(TPanel)
  private
    pnChild1: TPanel;
    pnChild2: TPanel;
  protected
    procedure Resize; override;
  end;

procedure TmyPanel.Resize;
begin
  // в этом примере предполагается, что у вложенных панелей выравнивание отсутствует.
  pnChild1.SetBounds(0, 0, ClientWidth, pnChild1.Height); // верхнюю панель выравниваем
  // a-la alTop
  pnChild2.SetBounds(
    pnChild1.Left, 
    pnChild1.Top+pnChild1.Height, 
    pnChild1.Width, 
    ClientHeight - (pnChild1.Top+pnChild1.Height));
  // возможно, здесь для лучшего эффекта стоит еще учитывать BevelWidth 
end;
```